# How I can specify a stylesheet into a fxml file?

Tags: java, css, javafx, stylesheet, fxml

Sorry for my bad english but I'm italian.

I'm trying to specify a stylesheet into a fxml file in this way

```
<stylesheets>
  <URL value="@../default.css" />
</stylesheets>
```

but I get this error:

**java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ../default.css**

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problem with the way you are using `<stylesheets>`. Can you show us the FXML? It'll help us to have the knowledge on how and where are you using the tag.

Answer (score 1):

`getStylesheets` returns a list of `String`s, not `URL`s. So you need

```
<stylesheets>
  <String fx:value="@../default.css" />
</stylesheets>
```

Comment: In this [Oracle Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm#CHDIHIAC) it uses `URL`. Even, I have used it inside layouts, without any issue.